# Is this a good git workflow

Tags: git

We are a small team of 5 people. Except me, the others do not prefer to learn details of git. The team is changing every year too.

We have been using [centralized workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-centralized) for a while. Everybody has write access to this central repository. Somehow it was working.

Lately, I found some code that should have been fixed for a while, so I thought somebody re-pushed the unfixed code. So, I want to move to a more controlled workflow.

I was considering [forking-workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-forking), but I wonder we will manage it, as people got used to central workflow already, and I do not know what kind of problems we will face with the forking workflow. Seems like a lot of merging will need to be done by everybody.

So, I was thinking, may be we should continue to have this central repository, but I should maintain an additional "safe repository" where only I would have write access. I would carefully fetch & merge to this one from central one. People can pull from "safe", push to "central".

What do you think, is this a good idea?

Comment: This might be a better question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Look at the "git flow" workflow (not posted as an answer since this should be moved to programmers SE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forking workflow is way overkill for a team of 5. It is usually used when there are hundreds or thousands of people working on a project and some of them are completely untrusted (read: open source projects). It would probably cause serious confusion and chaos. Everyone would have their own copy of every branch. Really not needed for a team of 5.

For any small professional team, the ['git workflow'](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow) will probably be best. This way each task has its own branch and then that branch can be merged into the main body of code when it is complete. You can do a code review at that point, or have only one knowledgeable person doing those merges so that nothing gets regressed. Each person would just have their own branch, rather than their own copy of every branch. Easy to understand.

I know that from the graphics on that page you linked, the git workflow *looks* more complex. But it actually isn't. It is between the 'centralized workflow' and the 'forking workflow' in complexity.